# The standard differentiable structure on $ \mathbb R^n $ and mappings $ \mathbb R\to X $

Tags: differential-geometry

I just started my journey into differentiable manifolds, and I was trying familiarize with the (somewhat) intricate definitions of (maximal) atlas, differentiable mapping and so on.

### A question about the standard differentiable structure on $ \mathbb R^n $

I've learned how an atlas $ \mathscr A $ (of $ \mathcal C^\infty $-compatible charts) on a set $ X $ induces a maximal atlas $ \mathscr S_{\mathscr A} $, and now I'm trying to use this fact to manifold-ize $ \mathbb R^n $. The atlas I chose is of course $ \mathscr A = \{(\mathbb R^n,1_{\mathbb R^n})\} $. The maximal atlas induced by $ \mathscr A $ is then the set $ \mathscr S_{\mathscr A} $ of all the charts on $ \mathbb R^n $ compatible with the "identity" chart $ (\mathbb R^n,1_{\mathbb R^n}) $. Should I conclude that the charts in $ \mathscr S_{\mathscr A} $ are exactly the pairs $ (U,\phi\colon U\to \underline U) $ where $ U,\underline U\subset \mathbb R^n $ are open sets and $ \phi $ is a $ \mathcal C^\infty $ diffeomorphism?

Indeed, if $ (V,\psi\colon V\to \underline V) $ is a pair of an open set $ V\subset \mathbb R^n $ and a homeomorphism $ \psi $ between $ V $ and another open subset $ \underline V $ belonging to $ \mathscr S_{\mathscr A} $, the $ \mathcal C^\infty $ compatibility condition with the chart $ (\mathbb R^n,1_{\mathbb R^n}) $ forces $ \psi $ to be infinitely differentiable. Assuming I'm good at math, of course.

In the end, does this implies that there exists at least one $ \mathcal C^k $ differentiable structure on $ \mathbb R^n $, one for each $ k $?

### A question about the differentiability of mappings $ \mathbb R\to X $ and $ X\to \mathbb R $

Let $ X $ and $ Y $ be two differentiable ($ \mathcal C^\infty $) manifolds. The definition of differentiable mapping $ f\colon X\to Y $ I have in mind is the following: $ f $ is *differentiable* if for every $ x\in X $ and for every chart $ (V,\psi) $ of $ Y $ around $ f(x) $, there exists a chart $ (U,\phi) $ of $ X $ around x such that $ f(U)\subset V $ and such that $ f_{\psi\phi} = \psi\circ f{\restriction_U^V}\circ \phi^{-1} $ is a $ \mathcal C^\infty $ mapping between euclidean spaces.

Now, I was trying to specialize this definition separately to the case where $ X = \mathbb R $ and $ Y = \mathbb R $.

I come up with the following when $ X = \mathbb R $: a function $ f\colon \mathbb R\to Y $ is differentiable if for every $ \xi\in \mathbb R $ and for every chart $ (V,\psi) $ of $ Y $ around $ f(\xi) $ there exists an open set $ N\subset \mathbb R $ around $ \xi $ (i.e., such that $ \xi\in N $) such that $ f(N)\subset V $ and such that the composite $ \psi\circ f{\restriction_N^V} $ is a $ \mathcal C^\infty $ mapping.

And with the following when $ Y = \mathbb R $: a function $ f\colon \mathbb R\to Y $ is differentiable if for every $ x1\in X $ there exists a chart $ (U,\phi) $ of $ X $ around $ x $ such that $ f{\restriction_U}\circ \phi^{-1} $ is a $ \mathcal C^\infty $ mapping of euclidean spaces.

Are these characterizations correct? Are there some other characterizations of differentiability for mappings $ \mathbb R\to Y $ or $ X\to \mathbb R $ I should be aware of?